# Magento 2 Custom install script won't work

Tags: database, upgrade, installation, migration

I am trying to create installation script that make a record to cms_page table.

So i created the next directory
/app/code/Magento/Page/

Here is my /etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Page" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

And registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'PageEdu2',
        __DIR__
    );
```

Here is InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Page\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->getConnection()->query("INSERT INTO inviqa_example SET name = 'Test 1'");
    }
}
```

Problem is that after installing i have no inviqa_example table in mysql.

After command `php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade` i have long module list. Last rows are next:
Module 'Page':
Please re-run Magento compile command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your class inserting data to the table, you need class wich create schema, call InstallSchema

for example

```
 namespace COmpany\youModule\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
         */
        public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {


        $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();

            /**
             * Create table 'customer_entity'
             */
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('inviqa_example')
            )->addColumn(
                'id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'Entity Id'
            )->addColumn(
                'somecolumn',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false],
                'api Id'
            )
               ->setComment(
            'comment'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
  }
```

or look for the same file in magento core modules